# onCreateView and onResume not being called after back button press

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with a `ViewPager` and 4 tabs.

One of the tabs is a `ListView` of objects with a create object button.
When I press this button, I replace my `ListFragment` inside the `ViewPager` with a `NewObjFragment`.

Inside it there is a small creation form and a submit button. When this button is pressed, I add my new object to Objects' list and then call `popBackStack()`.

Somehow nothing is being called (`onResume` or `onCreateView` ) on my `ListFragment`, so the list that appears is the old one, without my new object.

Also noticed that nothing is called when I press the back button, just `NewObjFragment` is removed, however, no `onCreateView` or `onResume` from `ObjectListsFragment` is called. 
My `ObjectListsFragment` is shown, but no method is called.

Why is this happening?

Comment: So you're using the system back button to store the information the user has inputted?

Comment: No, actually I noticed that `onCreateView` was not being called by previous fragment because when I pressed the back button, the title of the action bar would change, and it doesn't. Somehow I'm saving the previous fragment state, without clearly asking to do it.

Comment: Hmm...OK...either way, the system back button is not meant to be used as a "Submit" button. It's against the guidelines for one, and completely changes the behavior of the app. I suggest you add some sort of submit button in the activity and pass info using intents and bundles.

Comment: Think about it: I'm filling out a small form...when I'm done, I'm looking for a Submit button, not a back button. It's confusing.

Comment: I edited my final paragraph, the back button is not being used as a submit button. Actually I didn't override the back method. I'm just saying that when the fragment is removed, by pressing back button, the previous one is shown. But no method from previous fragment is called..

Comment: Ah...well that's a little better. But still, try adding a submit button that updates the info and closes the form.

Comment: My problem is not updating the info, in my case, a list of objects. My problem is that the previous fragment doesn't add the new object to the `ListView` because `onResume()` or `onCreateView()` are not called again... Maybe it's because I'm using nested fragments?

Comment: Do you call add() or replace() when adding a fragment, because if you just add it on top, the previous one is not destroyed, thus it won't go through onCreate() when you go back

Comment: Question for you: is the form a fragment and viewpager item or is it a new activity that opens from a viewpager item?

Comment: I call `replace` with `addToBackStack`. And the new form is a Fragment with some `EditText`s, but it replaces my `ListFragment`, so the `ViewPager` contains both. No new activity is created.

Comment: Did you solved your issue? I'm struggling around with the same problem here...

Comment: @Tobi, sorry for the waiting, I'm from brazil and posted the same question in the portuguese version of stack overflow, there a friend from my college solved my issue, The question is here http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59197/fragment-dentro-de-viewpager-n%C3%A3o-chama-nenhum-m%C3%A9todo 
But this git repo helped me a lot, basically you must have a `RootFragment` for the `ViewPager`, because it holds its fragment's states, and replace with the others. Doing this I solved my issue!
The repos is this -> https://github.com/danilao/fragments-viewpager-example
Any doubt, just call!

Comment: Also I replaced `getChildFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()` when calling `ViewPager` constructor

Comment: Thanks alot! I will take a look and I will tell, if I succeeded

Comment: No, not really. I'm trying to move the code to an ActivityBar so I can use tabs.

Comment: @Kayan: I solved it by using this example: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/   The only thing is, that I currently doesn't have ViewPager, but I will implement this in the future :)